# How to connect 4” PVC to broken sewer line?

Tags: pvc, sewer, cast-iron

I have a piece of broken cast iron pipe with almost no overhang. Wondering what are my options here?
[image]

Comment: What is this to? Toilet flange? Drain? 2 pipes connecting together?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How best to cut & tie into cast iron pipe](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/79264/how-best-to-cut-tie-into-cast-iron-pipe)

Comment: 'rubber donut insert' ... and an angle grinder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there was no easy way to fix it.
As a result, I had to dig outside, cut the cast iron outside (rented a tool at home depot) and then used rubber coupling to connect one to another

Answer (score 1):

I know that plastic convertors exist(ed) as the plumber used one for us...

You would need to remove material aound the pipe to provide sufficient connection.

I am not aware if they make an internal plastic version - but that would mean cleaning and sealing the internal surface which tends to be in worse condition that the outside...

Answer (score 1):

A [Fernco](https://www.fernco.com/products/flexible-couplings/stock-couplings#tid-186) (brand-name often used as a generic term) coupling is the standard approach, and you'd need to open up some space around the pipe to attach one. Otherwise you're going to need to dig outside and replace that section of pipe through the wall.

[image]

Not associated, though I may have to buy a couple to solve a problem on my plumbing.

The "[sheilded](https://www.fernco.com/plumbing/shielded-couplings)" variant adds a layer of metal to make the assembly more rigid and may be worth the additional cost.
[image]